# WPF Wrap panel not working for radio button with content template binding style?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new at WPF. I have list of radio button in menu of WPF application. I changed the style of radio button to look like textblock as submenu. Now problem is when I am trying to wrap and image and text inside radio button it's not showing it. but if i remove the style that I added on radio button to look and feel like textblock then wraping is just working fine but then it's display radion button Icon which I not needed.

Please refer to below code :

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonMenuStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
<Setter Property="Template">                      
<Setter.Value> 
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"> 
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"> 
<TextBlock.Style> 
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"> 
<Setter Property="Height" Value="36"/> 
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" /> 
<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
<Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/> 
<Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/> 
</TextBlock.Style> 
</TextBlock> 
</ControlTemplate> 
</Setter.Value> 
</Setter> 
</Style> 
</StackPanel.Resources>

------------------------------------------------------------------------

<RadioButton Name="rbttest" GroupName="rbtgroup" Background="{x:Null}" Style="   

{StaticResource RadioButtonMenuStyle}"  IsChecked="True">

<WrapPanel>
<Image Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/Test.ico" Width="16" Height="16"    
Margin="0,0,5,0" />
<TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Green" />
</WrapPanel>                    
</RadioButton>
```

Is the templateBinding Content causing the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template, you are binding `TextBlock.Text` to `RadioButton.Content`, but your `RadioButton` content is actually a UI element (`WrapPanel`).

Get rid of the `TextBlock` in the template and replace it with a `ContentPresenter`.  You don't need to set any properties on the presenter; it already knows how to locate the content on the templated parent.